# Using a custom manager function in a model definition

Tags: django, python-2.7

I'm trying to use manager function to populate a default field of a Model, but I'm having trouble getting it working. Here's my code:

```
class FooManager(models.Manager):
    def foo_filter(self):
        return Foo.objects.latest('id')

class Foo(models.Model):
    objects = FooManager()
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        unique=True,
        default=objects.foo_filter())
```

Whenever I run it, 
I get `NameError: global name 'Foo' is not defined` on the line `return Foo.objects.latest('id')`

Answer (score 1):

Ha! This is a cool one :)

When your `models.py` gets loaded for the first time, Python is trying to parse all the class definitions.

So the first thing it sees is `FooManager`, so far so good.
In your filter method you make use of `Foo`, which is still unknown at this point. Usually that would not be a problem, because you are using `Foo` in a method and that method only gets called during runtime, when all the classes are already loaded.

Now Python sees the `Foo` class and on the `name` field you are calling one of the manager's methods. At this point, when your filter method is called, the `Foo` class has not been fully loaded, yet, so when you enter the filter method, `Foo` is indeed not defined.

You would have to move the manager definition below the `Foo` definition, but you can't do that, because then the line `objects = FooManager()` would fail because `FooManager` would be undefined.

By the way: This is a very common newbie error: You must *never* put method calls into your field definitions. It means that the method is *only* executed once when the server starts and Django loads all the model definitions. This leads to extremely frustrating errors:

At first, the default value of your field is indeed the latest `Foo` object, but when you add a new object to the database, it will *not change* to the new latest object, it will stay the same object that was the latest when the server was started.

Django usually allows you to put methods into your field definitions, so you could write:

```
default=objects.foo_filter
```

without the `()`. Now, when the server is loaded, the method will not be executed. It will only be executed, when Django actually needs to retrieve the default value, and at that point in time, both, `FooManager` and `Foo` have already been loaded.

But apart from that, your manager doesn't even need to know which model it belongs to. Have a look at the Django docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/managers/#modifying-initial-manager-querysets

Each manager has a `get_queryset` method which you can override and which you should use, so you could do the following:

```
class FooManager(models.Manager):
    def foo_filter(self):
        return self.get_queryset().latest('id')
```

Now your manager doesn't use the `Foo` class at all and you won't get into any circular dependency problems.

By the way, I don't think that `latest('id')` will work, you have to pass in a field name that is a date field, not an ID field.

Answer (score -1):

You are create a loop, that object already *is* `Foo.objects`. All you need is:

```
def foo_filter(self):
    return self.latest('id')
```

On top of that you can't use the database to set defaults for a field like that.

Comment: Changing that value to self doesn't fix anything, it just this `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'`

> On top of that you can't use the database to set defaults for a field like that. 


This works, since I've done it with this function outside of a manager, I just want to port it inside a manager.